# Delphi Generic Template classes Usage Compilation Error

Tags: delphi, generics, compiler-errors

I am new to Delphi Generic Classes. I don't get it of how to use the generic classes in the implementation code. 
Here is the code:

```
Type TDataElement = class(TObject)
  protected
    Procedure SetName(sNewValue:String); virtual;
  private
    m_sName:String;
  published
    property sName:String read m_sName write SetName;
end;

Type TDataArray<T : TDataElement> = class(TObject)
  public

    function Find(dtElement:T):integer; 
    Procedure Add(dtElement:T);
  private
    m_vContainer : array of T;
  protected
    Function GetData(Index:integer):T; virtual;
    Procedure SetData(Index:integer; NewValue:T); virtual;
  public
    property vData[Index: Integer]: T read GetData write SetData;
end;

implementation

function TDataArray<T>.Find(dtElement:T):integer;
var i:integer;
begin
  Result:=-1;
  for i := 0 to high(m_vContainer) do
    if (m_vContainer[i] <> NIL)and(m_vContainer[i] = dtElement) then
    begin
      Result:=i;
      exit;
    end;
end;    
.....
```

When I try to create instances of the Generic Classes like in the following code:
**Method1)**

```
var z:TDataArray<TDataElement>;
    z:=TDataArray<TDataElement>.Create();
```

I get the following error:

**E2010 Incompatible types: 'TDataElement' and 'class of TDataElement'**

If I do this 2nd method I get another strange error:
**Method 2)**
    type TDataElementClass = class of TDataElement;

```
var  z:TDataArray<TDataElementClass>;
```

**F2084 Internal Error : I8230**

What I am doing wrong?

Entire source code in one file

```
  System.SysUtils,Classes,
  dtArray_unit in 'D:\VisionBot\Software\VisionBot\GUI\Units\dtArray_unit.pas';


Type TDataElement = class(TObject)
  protected
    Procedure SetName(sNewValue:String); virtual;
  private
    m_sName:String;
  published
    property sName:String read m_sName write SetName;
end;

Type TDataArray<T : TDataElement> = class(TObject)
  public

    function Find(dtElement:T):integer; overload;

    Procedure Add(dtElement:T);
  private

    m_vContainer : array of T;
  protected
    Function GetData(Index:integer):T; virtual;
    Procedure SetData(Index:integer; NewValue:T); virtual;
  public
    property vData[Index: Integer]: T read GetData write SetData;
end;

type
  TDerivedDataElement = class(TDataElement)
  end;

var
  z2: TDataArray<TDerivedDataElement>;


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Procedure TDataElement.SetName(sNewValue:String);
begin
  self.m_sName:=sNewValue;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function TDataArray<T>.Find(dtElement:T):integer;
var i:integer;
begin
  Result:=-1;
  for i := 0 to high(m_vContainer) do
    if (m_vContainer[i] <> NIL)and(m_vContainer[i] = dtElement) then
    begin
      Result:=i;
      exit;
    end;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function TDataArray<T>.GetData(Index:integer):T;
begin
  Result:=NIL;
  if Index < 0 then exit else
  if Index > high(Index) then exit else
  Result:=self.m_vContainer[Index];
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Procedure TDataArray<T>.Add(dtElement:T);
begin
  SetLength(self.m_vContainer,Length(m_vContainer)+1);
  m_vContainer[High(m_vContainer)]:=T;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Procedure TDataArray<T>.SetData(Index:integer; NewValue:T);
begin
  if Index < 0 then exit else
  if Index > high(Index) then exit else
  self.m_vContainer[Index]:=T;

end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


begin
  try

    z2:= TDataArray<TDerivedDataElement>.Create();

    readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: It seems that you are mixing metaclasses with classes. How is z declared? `T: TDataElement` means that you can substitute `T` with `TDataElement` class or any descendant class, but not with `TDataElement` metaclass (`class of TDataElement`).

Comment: I have absolutely no idea of the difference between metaclasses and classes. I did a small edit. Even I do this:     var z:TDataArray<TDataElement>;
        z:=TDataArray<TDataElement>.Create(); I still get the error (first method)

Comment: Note that the *internal error* is always an error in the compiler. That means you are not doing anything wrong, the compiler just ran into what was probably some edge case and can't handle it. Sometimes, rearranging the code or assigning intermediate results to variables or declaring types instead of ad-hoc declarations can help, but that is not guaranteed. Never forget that an internal error is not your fault.

Comment: Also note that a `class of x` is not the class `x` itself, it is a type that can be used to obtain information *about* the class `x`, i.e. a so called *metaclass*. The "mother" of such types is the `TClass` type. Such a metaclass can also be used with virtual constructors to create an instance of the actual class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var  
  z: TDataArray<TDataElementClass>;
```

The problem is that `TDataElementClass` is not a class derived from `TDataElement`.

The following would be valid:

```
var  
  z: TDataArray<TDataElement>;
```

Or this:

```
type
  TDerivedDataElement = class(TDataElement)
  end;

var  
  z: TDataArray<TDerivedDataElement>;
```

In your code you have

```
type
  TDataElementClass = class of TDataElement;
```

Now, `TDataElementClass` is a [metaclass](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_References#Class-Reference_Types).

- A variable of type `TDataElement` can hold an **instance** of the type `TDataElement`, or an instance of any class derived from `TDataElement`.
- A variable of type `TDataElementClass` can hold a **type**, which must be `TDataElement`, or any class derived from `TDataElement`.

You claim in the question that using `TDataArray<TDataElement>` leads to a compiler error, but that is not true. Consider this compiling program:

```
type
  TDataElement = class
  end;

type
  TDataArray<T: TDataElement> = class
  public
    function Find(dtElement: T): Integer;
  private
    m_vContainer: array of T;
  end;

function TDataArray<T>.Find(dtElement: T): Integer;
begin
  for Result := 0 to high(m_vContainer) do
    if (m_vContainer[Result] <> nil) and (m_vContainer[Result] = dtElement) then
      exit;
  Result := -1;
end;

var
  arr: TDataArray<TDataElement>;

begin
  arr := TDataArray<TDataElement>.Create;
end.
```

---

In your edit you show this code:

```
Procedure TDataArray<T>.Add(dtElement:T);
begin
  SetLength(self.m_vContainer,Length(m_vContainer)+1);
  m_vContainer[High(m_vContainer)]:=T;
end;
```

The erroneous line is here:

```
m_vContainer[High(m_vContainer)]:=T;
```

This fails because `T` is a type rather than an instance. I think you mean:

```
m_vContainer[High(m_vContainer)]:=dtElement;
```

Comment: I tried the second method in Delphi XE 3 "type
  TDerivedDataElement = class(TDataElement)
  end;

var  
  z: TDataArray<TDerivedDataElement>;"" and I get the error message E2010 Incompatible types: 'TDerivedDataElement' and 'class of TDerivedDataElement'

Comment: That claim is not backed up by facts. You didn't show all of your code. You omitted the code that makes your program fail to compile. I included a complete program that compiles to demonstrate.

Comment: I edited my first post including my full source code. Why mine is not compiling? The error message for my full code is E2010 Incompatible types: 'TDerivedDataElement' and 'class of TDerivedDataElement'

Comment: I indentified that my additional method including the Add method raise that error. Why? Procedure TDataArray<T>.Add(dtElement:T);
begin
  SetLength(self.m_vContainer,Length(m_vContainer)+1);
  m_vContainer[High(m_vContainer)]:=T;
end;

Comment: I've explained that now. A lesson to learn is the importance of producing a [mcve] with such a question.